# Opamp Circuit Analysis

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, analog

[image]

[image]

I have attached the problem and my attempt with the solution. The official answer to the problem is option(B). Please guide me where I am going wrong in solving it.

Comment: did you use the 0.7V threshold?

Comment: You mean I should have done (2.425-0.7)/5 = 0.345. But why as it is saying that there is negligible ON resistance? Sorry if I am asking a silly ques, I am weak with mosfets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miscalculated the value of the voltage at output of op-amp A1. It should be
$$V = 2.5 - 10*0.075 = 1.75$$
The switch will be on so duty cycle will become,
$$\frac{1.75*100}{5} = 35 \%$$

Comment: That was a silly mistake !! Thanks for pointing it out.